# Unable to install "App" Xcode Version 11.6 beta

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

gives an error when connecting a second iPhone, details of the error are presented below.

I also tried to fix the error by the answers in another discussion: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242678/xcode-error-the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-re

did not help

```
Details

Unable to install "App"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620383
--
The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620383
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008021)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001276e481a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000127725f70 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010e3faf25 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000127725ca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1654
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000012759ce91 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4165
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010e52e5c4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010e530206 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6db806c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6db81658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6db86c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6db875d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6db90c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6dddba3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6dddab77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--
```

Comment: could it be because the provisioning profile in the developer portal? could you try remove an existing provisioning profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that error 1 time, restart my Mac and in XCode I entered my Apple account again and the error disappeared.

Or maybe you can make another account and use it, sometimes xcode goes crazy, it has worked for me to close it and restart it, I hope it helps you.